# Confusion Regarding deepest pit within an Array

Tags: algorithm

I got this question as prerequisite for an interview,

> A non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers is given. A
>   pit in this array is any triplet of integers (P, Q, R) such that: 0 ≤
>   P < Q < R < N;
>
> sequence [A[P], A[P+1], ..., A[Q]] is strictly decreasing, i.e. A[P] >
>   A[P+1] > ... > A[Q];
>
> sequence A[Q], A[Q+1], ..., A[R] is strictly increasing, i.e. A[Q] <
>   A[Q+1] < ... < A[R].
>
> The depth of a pit (P, Q, R) is the number min{A[P] − A[Q], A[R] −
>   A[Q]}. For example, consider array A consisting of 10 elements such
>   that:
>
> ```
> A[0] =  0
> A[1] =  1
> A[2] =  3
> A[3] = -2
> A[4] =  0
> A[5] =  1
> A[6] =  0
> A[7] = -3
> A[8] =  2
> A[9] =  3
> ```
>
> Triplet (2, 3, 4) is one of pits in this array, because sequence
>   [A[2], A[3]] is strictly decreasing (3 > −2) and sequence [A[3], A[4]]
>   is strictly increasing (−2 < 0). Its depth is min{A[2] − A[3], A[4] −
>   A[3]} = 2.
>
> Triplet (2, 3, 5) is another pit with depth 3.
>
> Triplet (5, 7, 8) is yet another pit with depth 4. There is no pit in
>   this array deeper (i.e. having depth greater) than 4.

It says that Triplet (5, 7, 8) has the deepest pit depth of 4.

but isn't Triplet (2, 7, 9) has the deepest pit depth 6?

corresponding value of Triplet (2, 7, 9) is (3, -3, 3) and it also satisfies the conditions mentioned, i.e.

```
1) 0 ≤ P < Q < R < N
2) A[P] > A[P+1] > ... > A[Q] and A[Q] < A[Q+1] < ... < A[R]
```

so in this case min{A[P] − A[Q], A[R] − A[Q]} is 6.

What am i missing here?

***P.S.*** if you think this post does not belong here in this forum then please point out where should i post it.

Comment: The sequence `[A[2], A[3], ..., A[7]]` is not strictly decreasing. `A[3] < A[4]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the sequence from `P` to `Q` for `2 to 7`.

It is `3 -2 0 1 0 -3`.

> sequence [A[P], A[P+1], ..., A[Q]] is strictly decreasing, i.e. A[P] > A[P+1] > ... > A[Q];

The rule says that this should be a decreasing sequence. But it isn't. `3>-2` but `-2 is not greater than 0`. **Here the sequence breaks.**

From `7 to 9`. No problem as the sequence is increasing. `-3<2<3`.

Comment: gottcha. thank you for pointing that out, i messed up `A[p] > A[p+1]` with `p > p=1`. its the value stored withing the array that need to follow the rule.

Comment: @Ankit Yes, the whole sequence in between has to be considered.

Answer (score 0):

> answer of the deepest pit problem in swift :

```
 func solution(_ array: [Int]) -> Int {

        //guaranty we have at least three elements
        if array.isEmpty  {
            print("isEmpty")
            return -1
        }

        if array.count < 3 {
            print("is less than 3")
            return -1
        }

        //extremum point; max or min points
        var extremumPoints = [Int]()

        //adding first element
        extremumPoints.append(array[0])

        //calculate extremum points for 1 to one before last element
        for i in 1..<(array.count - 1) {

            let isRelativeExtremum = ((array[i] - array[i - 1]) * (array[i] - array[i + 1])) > 0
            //we call a point semi-extremum if a point is equal to previous element or next element and not equal to previous element or next element
            let isSemiExtremum = ((array[i] != array[i - 1]) && (array[i] == array[i + 1])) || ((array[i] != array[i + 1]) && (array[i] == array[i - 1]))

            if isRelativeExtremum || isSemiExtremum {
                extremumPoints.append(array[i])
            }
        }

        //adding last element
        extremumPoints.append(array[array.count - 1])

        //we will hold depthes in this array
        var depthes = [Int]()

        for i in 1..<(extremumPoints.count - 1) {

            let isBottomOfaPit = extremumPoints[i] < extremumPoints[i - 1] && extremumPoints[i] < extremumPoints[i + 1]

            if isBottomOfaPit {

                let d1 = extremumPoints[i - 1] - extremumPoints[i]
                let d2 = extremumPoints[i + 1] - extremumPoints[i]
                let d = min(d1, d2)
                depthes.append(d)
            }

        }

        //deepest pit
        let deepestPit = depthes.max()
        return deepestPit ?? -1
    }
```

//****************************

```
let A = [0,1,3,-2,0,1,0,-3,2,3]
let deepestPit = solution(A)
print(deepestPit) // 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def deepest(A):     
    def check(p, q, r, A):
        if A[p] > A[q] and A[q] < A[r]:
            return min(A[p] - A[q], A[r] - A[q])
        else:
            return -1
    max_depth = 0
    for i in range(1, len(A) - 2):
        if A[i-1] > A[i] < A[i + 1]:
            p = i
            r = i
            while 0 <= p and r <= len(A) - 1:
                depth = check(p, i, r, A)
                max_depth = max(max_depth, depth)
                p -= 1
                r += 1
    return max_depth
```

Comment: This is my answer.